# Number converter

Tags: numbers, converters

I would
Like to create a number converter based on values.
So the number entered changed into a new number based on what numbers are entered

User enters number to be converted-

Logic rules -

Odd numbers - 1,3,5,7,9 replaced with 0
Even numbers - 2, 4,6,8 replaced with 1

So if the numbers 2576 was entered the return value would be 1001

I only want numerical values to be entered, any alphabet values should bring up a error

I have tried if/elif/ else but I can’t seem to get any functionality to the code - does anyone have any suggestions or pointers to what type of function I need to use ?

Comment: This is a help community no coding service. Please post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which language you are using, but a general solution is to iterate over your input number as a string and check every char. If it is an odd digit, change the char to 0, if even then change to 1. And if you encountered anything but a digit, throw an error.